# Laravel 5 - read files that come in as an array of objects

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I'm sending some files to a Laravel server using AngularJs. The call to the server is:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/go/upload', 
    data: {
        uploaded_file: $scope.files
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
            formData.append(key, value);
        });

        var headers = headersGetter();
        delete headers['Content-Type'];

        return formData;
    }
}).success();
```

Debugging the files from the client side gives an array of File objects as this screenshot:

[image]

... which is all fine. But, for some reasons, on the API server (Laravel 5), I can't seem to process these files:

```
$files = $request->file('uploaded_file');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($files); // Empty
echo "</pre>";
die;
```

How do I process multiple files sent from AngularJs to Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

Append 'uploaded_file' to the formData file key:

```
formData.append('uploaded_file', formData.file);
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it - could you please explain why this answer?

Comment: You're not giving an identifier for the file being captured. Think of it like the name attribute in form fields.